# error [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, selenium

Error comes up only when I add this part of the code

```
<listeners>
<listener class-name ="automation.MyCoolIlistener"></listener>
</listeners>
```

without the previous ones the code is executed successfully
complete code

```
<suite name="My test suite" >
<listeners>
<listener class-name ="automation.MyCoolIlistener"></listener>
</listeners>
<parameter name= "stringA" value ="I love "/> 
<parameter name= "stringB" value ="test automation"/>       
<test name="My first test">
<classes>
<class name="automation.automationTest"/>
</classes>

</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: are you sure `javascript` is the correct tag?

Comment: you're right in XML, thanks